# How to make not only one object of class ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create array of Events  instead of one with same params except event.id . This is code :

```
 def create

    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.user_id = current_user.id



    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

How should I do this?

UPD
Event params :

```
 def event_params

      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :start_time, :end_time, :repeat)
    end
```

Comment: how many objects you want to create and what will be there in event_params?

Comment: @user123 in params i have title start time end time and user id. For example 10 objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    def create
      (1..10).each do |i|
        params[:event][:user_id] = current_user.id
        params[:event][:start_time] = params[:event][:start_time] + 24.hours  if i > 1
        params[:event][:end_time] = params[:event][:end_time] + 24.hours  if i > 1
        @event = Event.new(event_params)
        @event.save
      end
      redirect_to events_path
    end
```